# free(src) after memcpy(dst, src, n) causes a segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Consider the code below:

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int prt = 6;
    serial_port *cprt = open_comport(prt);

    int n;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        ubx_raw *msg = malloc(sizeof(ubx_raw));
        uint8_t *buf = malloc(1024*sizeof(uint8_t));
        n = RS232_PollComport(cprt->nr, buf, 1024);

        msg = ubx_acquire_frombuf(buf, n);
        //PROBLEM
        free(buf);
        if (msg == NULL)
        {
            printf("Message scrambled or no message in the buffer!\n");
            free(msg);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Length: %" PRIu16 "\n", msg->length);
        }

        free(buf);
        Sleep(1000);
        if (msg == NULL)
        {
            free(msg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with the function

```c
ubx_raw *ubx_acquire_frombuf(uint8_t *buf, int size)
{
    ubx_raw *msg = malloc(sizeof(ubx_raw));
    int n = 0;
    //sweep through bytes
    while (n < size - 1)
    {
        //check if start of message
        if ((buf[0] == UBX_SYNC1) && (buf[1] == UBX_SYNC2))
        {
            //put stuff into msg
            msg->length = ((uint16_t)*(buf+4));
            //check if full message available, otherwise
            //reduce amount to memcpy
            if (msg->length < size)
            {
                size = msg->length;
            }
            //PROBLEMATIC
            memcpy(&msg->data, &buf, size);
            return msg;
        }
        else
        {
            n++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Whenever `ubx_acquire_frombuf()` is called (near the start of the `while` loop in `main`) the subsequent `free(buf)` gives a segfault. Clearly, something bad is happening to `buf` in that function. I know you can't `free()` stuff that isn't `malloc()`'d and you can't `free()` stuff twice. Actually, because pointers are passed by value, what goes on inside `ubx_acquire_frombuf()` should be irrelevant to main, right?

Anyhow, commenting out the PROBLEMATIC `memcpy()` (in `ubx_acquire_frombuf()`) removes the segfault. How so? I still want to use that `memcpy`! Can anyone shed some light on what's going on? `memcpy()` shouldn't be editing the source from which it's copying (i.e. `buf`), right?

P.S. apologies for not having a minimal example, but I couldn't recreate the problem from scratch. I'm not sure what's happening but there isn't anything unusual (i.e. calls to other functions written by me) in `ubx_acquire_frombuf()` so this isn't too far off a minimal example.

---

EDIT: By popular demand:

```c
typedef struct {
  uint8_t *data;
  uint16_t length;
} ubx_raw;
```

Comment: `memcpy(&msg->data, &buf, size);` smells bad. Are you sure you don't mean `memcpy(&msg->data, buf, size);`? If you overwrite data `malloc()` needs in order to manage its buffer, that can cause `free()` to crash.

Comment: if ( msg == null ) --> free( msg ) sure it is not !=?

Comment: For that matter, should it be `msg->data` instead of `&msg->data`, assuming `data` is an array? If `data` is instead a pointer, you haven't allocated any memory for it to point *to*, so that would be a separate problem.

Comment: @mah oops, I do mean `memcpy(... buf ...)` instead of `memcpy(... &buf ...)`. Does that make a difference though? The problem is freeing `buf`, not `msg`.

Comment: @kbau The problem is that in both the `&buf` case and (probably) `&msg->data`, you're accessing memory you don't own.

Comment: @kbau Please show the `ubx_raw` declaration so we can see which of several problems are involved in your writing to `&msg->data`

Comment: `malloc`ing `msg->data` and doing `memcpy(msg->data, buf, size)`. Did it.

@MarioTheSpoon (msg==null, etc) thing - yeah, you're right, it's !=.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Beyond the errors already noted (there are *numerous*), you're also completely at the mercy of platform-specific endian storage. You'd better know *exactly* what this does:  `msg->length = ((uint16_t)*(buf+4))`, and whether or not the raw octets you're interpreting as a multi-byte scalar type are indeed presented in the consuming platform byte-order you're assuming.

Comment: OT: `main()` leaks the memory allocated here: `ubx_raw *msg = malloc(sizeof(ubx_raw));`.

Comment: Just to clarify, msg->data is indeed a pointer.

Comment: Are you aware that you don't change anything in the loop based on n?

Comment: "*`msg->data` is indeed a pointer*" so where does it get memory allocated too?

Comment: You might like to read this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ also make friends with Valgrind (https://valgrind.org)

Comment: @alk it didn't get any memory allocated (oops). Cheers for the article, I'll read through it!

Comment: Code does `free(buf);` twice on same pointer in `main()`.  This is certainly a problem.  Eliminate one of them.

Comment: @stark I'm aware of it now. I should be checking the values of buf[n] and buf[n+1].

Comment: Also this `if (msg == NULL)
        {
            free(msg);
        }` is useless.

Comment: @chux geez, it does. Code seems to be working now though. Removed the spare free now.

Comment: @alk mean to be `if (msg != NULL) etc`

Comment: Also useless, `free()` accepts a `NULL`-pointer.

Comment: @alk I was under the impression that free(NULL) is undefined. Quick google search confirmed your point though.

Comment: And be aware you there are two calls to `free()` where `msg` is pointing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you mark as problematic is, indeed, problematic:

```
// PROBLEMATIC
memcpy(&msg->data, &buf, size);
```

The problem is that you are copying `size` bytes to the field `msg->data` (because you are passing the address of `msg->data` to memcpy), but that field is just a pointer whose size is quite small. So the memcpy will overwrite the rest of the `ubx_raw` structure and then whatever follows it in memory, which will include some of `malloc`'s internal accounting information.

You probably meant

```
// PROBLEMATIC
memcpy(msg->data, &buf, size);
```

but that is still problematic, because `msg->data` has never been initialized. So a more likely solution is:

```
// NOT PROBLEMATIC but don't forget to free(msg->data) before free(msg).
msg->data = malloc(size); // Check for non-NULL
memcpy(msg->data, &buf, size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Few points that are suspicious;
1)why we are using &buf in **memcpy(&msg->data, &buf, size);**

2) why we are not doing buff++ in

```
n++;
buff++;//should be added
continue; //This is useless
```

3) When you do **ubx_raw *msg = malloc(sizeof(ubx_raw));**

I am not sure that what is memory allocated to msg->data. Or it is initialized to junk pointer.

I see many pain points but first these needs to cleared.

Comment: As looking at the ubx_raw struct, you should allocate memory first to msg->data and then do memcpy to it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the declaration of ubx_raw is the culprit.
for example, if `uxb_raw` is defined as

```
struct uxb_raw {
    uint8_t *data;
};
```

then the `sizeof(uxb_raw)` operation only returns the size of the pointer, not the size of whatever `uxb_raw.data` should point to. However, if you have declared

```
#define MAX_DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH 15
struct uxb_raw {
    uint8_t data[MAX_DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH];
};
```

Then `sizeof(uxb_raw)` will return the correct number of Bytes. If you want a malloced array of data, for example, in your main you might want to create `msg` like so:

```
struct uxb_raw msg = {.data = malloc(MAX_DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH * sizeof(uint8_t))};
```

In your `ubx_acquire_frombuf` function check that the *buf array size is no greater than `MAX_DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH` before copying data.

Comment: I didn't see the edit with the actual struct definition. The only change to my answer would be to set `uxb_raw.length = MAX_DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH`